# Batch rename filename in subfolder

Tags: batch-file, subdirectory

What do I have to change here in this code so it could do also subfolders?
Or if it is easier to run only through subfolders?

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%F in (*.jpg) do (
  set "name=%%F"
  ren "!name!" "!name:_=!"
)
```

This runs ok in current folder it erase in jpg filename character "_", but I don't know how to do it in subfolders, and that is my main goal to do.

Comment: use the `/R` switch of the For Command. Open `cmd.exe` and query `For /?` to learn command usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to use a `For /R` loop:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
For /R . %%G In ("*_*.jpg") Do (
    Set "name=%%~nxG"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    If Not Exist "%%~dpG!name:_=!" Ren "%%G" "!name:_=!"
    EndLocal
)
```

I have used a `.` character after `/R` to signify the current directory as the recursion base, whilst this is not necessary, because the current directory is assumed if no path is provided, it serves as a reminder, the you could include another path there if needed.

---

Although you could also use a `For /F` loop, with the `Dir` command:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %%G In ('Dir /B/S/A:-D "*_*.jpg"') Do (
    Set "name=%%~nxG"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    If Not Exist "%%~dpG!name:_=!" Ren "%%G" "!name:_=!"
    EndLocal
)
```

In this case, if you wanted to use a directory other than the current directory, you can insert it directly in the `Dir` glob, e.g. `"C:\SomePath\*_*.jpg"`

---

Please note however, in both cases, no attempt has been made to ensure that the remaining string, after removal of the underscores is a valid filename. It is your responsibility to incorporate such a check, if you wish to have robust code in your environment. Additionally no check is included to ensure that short filenames, *(8.3)*, are not matched, so if this could be an issue in your target environments, then you should include modifications or additions to cater for that.

Comment: Thank you, the first code does it what I need, I will now try to examine it to learn how it works. Thank you again. Best regards.